# moment.js diff between two timezone formatted dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have to calculate a time difference between a set time and the current server time.

I'm using the momentjs and the moment timezone library.

Here's what I have:

```
var serverTime = moment.tz(new Date(), "Europe/Berlin").format();
var bar = moment.tz("2016-05-14 00:00:00", "Europe/Berlin").format();
var baz = bar.diff(serverTime);

console.log('server time is: ' + serverTime);
console.log('time diff is: ' + baz);
```

This gives me an error:

```
TypeError: bar.diff is not a function
```

Is it possible to diff between two timezone formatted dates? If not, what's the optimal way to conduct such calculation using the momentjs library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`format` produces a string, so don't use it until you need a string.

```
var now = moment.tz("Europe/Berlin");
var bar = moment.tz("2016-05-14 00:00:00", "Europe/Berlin");
var baz = bar.diff(now);

console.log('current time is: ' + now.format());
console.log('time diff is: ' + baz);
```

Note that it's not the "server time" unless you're running this code on the server.  As long as it's running on the client, it's still based on the client's clock - even if you use a different time zone.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I should have named the variable better. I'm using the diff method between dates both converted into the timezone I specified so I'm getting the desired result. I wonder however if using utc is a good idea for emulating server time.

Comment: If you're just *comparing* the times, you don't even need to specify any particular time zone because it's using UTC under the hood.  I only included the TZ on the first line because you display it later.  If you only care about the diff, you can just use `moment()`.

Comment: WRT "server time", the only way to *truely* do that is by getting a timestamp from the server - and of course you have to consider that there are delays in transmitting that timestamp.  You seem to be conflating "using the server's time zone" with "using the server's clock".  Keep in mind that the client can change their clock to anything they want.  There's no guarantee it will be in sync.

Answer (score 0):

moment.js is truly great!

It seems I can simply do:

```
moment.duration(day14.diff(serverTime)).asHours();
```

or to get the digits for the minutes and hours separately

```
moment.duration(day14.diff(serverTime)).minutes();
moment.duration(day14.diff(serverTime)).hours();
```